# Segmentation Fault core dumped when using array subscripting

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a fairly basic program but I am getting a dumped core. Any ideas of what I am doing incorrectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void){


    char *number [] = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eigth","nine"};
    char *object [] = {"sf","sfe","sefg","efsef","seg","eshse","segeg","ryte","asrh","asegh"};

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        printf("In this code %s\n this should %s\n work\n\n",number[i],object[i]);


    }


}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing your loop counts to 10 yet your number array only has 9 items.

Comment: Like Joe said: if number has 9 items, their indices are number[0] to number[8], and in your example i's last value is 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic 'off by one' error. There are too few elements in your '`number`' array. There are ten elements in `object`, but only nine in `number`.

Answer (score 1):

Joe has it right: your loop gos from 0 to 9, ie, ten items.  You want 0 to 8.

This is a real common beginner mistake btw.

The pattern is

```
for index = 0; while index is less than length; add one to index
```